Why is using Start-Process to re-launch a .cmd in admin mode not using my default terminal?
I have some .cmd files which need to be run as admin. They have this at the start of each file, to detect if not running as admin, and re-launch as an admin if not:
:: If not admin, restarts the script with admin privileges
NET FILE 1>nul 2>nul
if '%errorlevel%' == '0' (
    goto adminTasks 
) else (
    echo Restarting with admin privileges...
    POWERSHELL saps -filepath '%0' -verb runas 1>nul 2>nul
)
exit /b

:adminTasks
:: bla bla bla

The petty thing that's bugging me is that I've just downloaded Windows Terminal, and set it as my default terminal application in the settings. When I run this script, it now briefly opens in terminal, but when it closes and I hit yes to the admin prompt, it opens it back in old windows command prompt.
I've played around and noticed if I use start-process to run a .cmd file, if I include "-verb runas", it always uses command prompt. If I omit that, it uses terminal.
Anyone have any idea what's going on? Am I being an idiot?

Found the answer, it's a known issue: https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/10276#issuecomment-852215012

I recommend reading How to Set the Default Terminal Application in Windows 11.
The Windows 11 setting for Terminal is stored in the registry hive of the current user under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console\%%Startup as follows:

Let Windows decide
DelegationConsole is with string value {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
DelegationTerminal is with string value {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
Windows Console Host
DelegationConsole is with string value {B23D10C0-E52E-411E-9D5B-C09FDF709C7D}
DelegationTerminal is with string value {B23D10C0-E52E-411E-9D5B-C09FDF709C7D}
Windows Terminal
DelegationConsole is with string value {2EACA947-7F5F-4CFA-BA87-8F7FBEEFBE69}
DelegationTerminal is with string value {E12CFF52-A866-4C77-9A90-F570A7AA2C6B}

The Windows 11 setting Terminal is not a local machine setting. It is a current user setting. That is very important to know in this use case. The two registry values are not evaluated at all on running a batch file as administrator. The Terminal setting is never considered in this use case. Read further on being interested in the reason.
The usage of %SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe with the cmdlet Start-Process with -verb RunAs is like right clicking on the batch file in Windows File Explorer and clicking in the opened context menu on the item Run as administrator. There is also opened a standard console window and not a Terminal window on execution of a batch file with Run as administrator from Windows shell (desktop, start menu, taskbar) or a Windows File Explorer window.
There is just one difference between the PowerShell and the Explorer execution:

The batch file name as passed to cmd.exe as argument 0 is passed further to powershell.exe without any modification while the execution of the batch file with Run as administrator with Explorer results in passing the fully qualified batch file name further by explorer.exe.

Please read my answer on Why does 'Run as administrator' change (sometimes) batch file's current directory? There is explained in full details what happens now in the background after several registry accesses to determine which executable with which options to run for running the batch file as local administrator in an elevated execution environment.
There is passed to PowerShell with %0 just the string of argument 0 of the batch file like it was passed to cmd.exe on starting the execution of the batch file with the current user account. A double click on the batch file results in explorer.exe is calling the Windows kernel library function CreateProcess for execution of cmd.exe with the fully qualified file name of the batch file as one of the arguments. %0 is in this case the fully qualified batch file name.
But it is also possible to run the batch file by entering just its file name without file extension and without full path or with a relative path in a Command Prompt, PowerShell Console or Terminal window like ..\test for execution of test.cmd in the parent directory of the current directory. In this case the argument 0 on batch file execution is ..\test and %0 passes that string to powershell.exe. PowerShell checks the existence of the file and replaces the file name with relative path to a fully qualified file name.
The current working directory can change to %SystemRoot%\System32 as it can be read in the referenced answer and cmd.exe would fail to find the batch file or runs a completely different batch file with name test found in the Windows directory if PowerShell would not modify ..\test to the fully qualified file name.
The missing file extension is also not good here in case of there is in the parent directory test.cmd found first by cmd.exe and test.ps1 found first by PowerShell. PowerShell would output with test.ps1 found in the parent directory the error message:
Start-Process : This command cannot be run due to the error: No application is associated with the specified file for
this operation.
At line:1 char:1
+ Start-Process -filepath '..\test' -verb RunAs
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand

There is no user account control prompt opened at all asking the user for running the Windows Command Processor in elevated execution environment.
A solution is using %~f0 instead of %0. See also: What's the difference between %0 and %~f0?
The batch file should be modified to:
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
rem If not admin, restart the script with admin privileges.
%SystemRoot%\System32\net.exe FILE 1>nul 2>nul
if not errorlevel 1 goto AdminTasks

echo Restarting with admin privileges...
%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe Start-Process -FilePath '"%~f0"' -verb RunAs
rem endlocal is executed implicit by cmd.exe on exiting.
exit /b

:AdminTasks
echo Current directory: %CD%
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo CMD started with: !CMDCMDLINE!
endlocal
pause
endlocal

It is best to specify the required execution environment completely in the batch file as done with the first two command lines and do not depend on settings which are set outside of the batch file by the parent processes.
It is best to specify all file names with a well-known path with their fully qualified file names to have a batch file which does not depend on the environment variables PATH and PATHEXT. The batch file is also executed faster in this case because of the Windows Command Processor does not need to search for the files.
I recommend opening a command prompt window, running if /? and reading the output help. The IF condition to check if a command or executable exited with exit code 0 usually indicating a successful execution assigned to the dynamic variable ERRORLEVEL should be if not errorlevel 1 (direct check of the integer value of the dynamic variable) and not if '%errorlevel%' == '0' (string comparison after variable expansion). The condition if not errorlevel 1 means IF ERRORLEVEL NOT GREATER OR EQUAL 1 which is IF ERRORLEVEL LESS THAN 1 which is IF ERRORLEVEL EQUAL 0 as no Windows command exits ever with a negative value.
This batch file works now by design and not anymore by chance as long as %~f0 does not expand to a string containing & as that results in a wrong interpretation of the fully qualified batch file name by cmd.exe in elevated execution environment.
This demonstration code shows a user also how the execution environment changes by running the batch file as administrator. The current working directory in elevated execution environment is output and also how the Windows Command Processor was started by PowerShell with calling the Windows kernel library function CreateProcessAsUser for execution of the Windows Command Processor with option /C and the fully qualified batch file name enclosed in " as one more argument.
Processes are executables of which file names have usually the file extension .exe or .com on Windows. A batch file is not an executable. That results in lots of Windows registry accesses to find out which executable to run for running the batch file as administrator on calling CreateProcessAsUser by powershell.exe.
It is possible with free Windows Sysinternals (Microsoft) tool Process Monitor to view all registry and file system accesses done on execution of the batch file. After downloading the ZIP file and extracting it into a local directory, run Process Monitor as administrator (required), accept the EULA, and add three filter rules:

Process Name is cmd.exe then Include
Process Name is conhost.exe then Include
Process Name is poweshell.exe then Include

Then open a Terminal or a Command Prompt window, change the current working directory to the directory of the batch file and run the batch file by typing its name and pressing RETURN or ENTER.
Confirm the user account control prompt on current user account is in the members list of the local group Administrators. It is otherwise even necessary to use a completely different account for running the batch file as administrator and the user must therefore select a different account and enter the current password of the different account. The command lines below the label AdminTasks should not contain command lines which modify files/folders or registry key/values of current user as the now used user account is different to the user account on initial start of the batch file.
I executed from the directory C:\Temp a batch file with the execution of "Development + Test 99% (!)" (no path and no file extension). The output after confirmation of running the batch file as administrator was:
Current directory: C:\Windows\System32
CMD started with: "C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe" /C "C:\Temp\Development + Test 99% (!).cmd"
Press any key to continue . . .

Looks good. The current working directory changes, but that was already expected.
I renamed the batch file to Development & Test 100% (!).cmd, executed it with "Development & Test 100% (!)" and confirmed running it as administrator. There is just for a very short time opened a console window. There is no output visible. The same happened on right clicking on batch file Development & Test 100% (!).cmd in Explorer and clicking in context menu on Run as administrator.
The reason can be seen on viewing the Process Monitor log by double clicking on any line of cmd.exe started in elevated execution environment (look on PID – process identifier) and switch to tab Process. The Windows Command Processor is started in this case with:
C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe /C "C:\Temp\Development & Test 100% (!).cmd"

That looks right. Why is the batch file not processed by cmd.exe in elevated execution environment?
There can be executed cmd /? in a command prompt window to get output the usage help of cmd.exe. The help explains in detail how the argument(s) after option /C (run command line and close) or option /K (run command line and keep running) are interpreted by cmd.exe. In this case the first and last " are removed by cmd.exe and the remaining string is parsed by cmd.exe as command line to execute. It interprets & as conditional command operator as explained by single line with multiple commands. CMD searches therefore for a file matching the wildcard pattern C:\Temp\Development.* and gets returned from the file system that there is no such file. CMD searches next in current directory and then in all directories as listed in PATH for a file with name test with a file extension as listed in PATHEXT and fails to find such a file too. The result is a self-closing of cmd.exe as nothing more to do.
The usage of %SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe Start-Process -FilePath '"%~f0"' -verb RunAs will not work due to this misinterpretation of the argument string after option /C by CMD on fully qualified file name contains anywhere inside one or even more &. There would be extra code needed in the batch file to work around this issue like following:
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
rem If not admin, restart the script with admin privileges.
%SystemRoot%\System32\net.exe FILE 1>nul 2>nul
if errorlevel 1 (goto Elevate) else goto AdminTasks

:GetBatchName
set "BatchName=%~f0" & goto :EOF

:Elevate
call :GetBatchName
if not "%BatchName:&=%" == "%BatchName%" for %%I in ("%BatchName%") do set "BatchName=%%~sI"
if not "%BatchName:&=%" == "%BatchName%" goto Failure
echo Restarting with admin privileges...
%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe Start-Process -FilePath '"%BatchName%"' -verb RunAs
exit /B

:Failure
echo(
echo Please do not run this batch file from within a directory of
echo which full path contains anywhere the character ^&  as that
echo does not work. The batch file name should be also without
echo an ampersand character. Thank you.
echo(
pause
rem endlocal is executed implicit by cmd.exe on exiting.
exit /b

:AdminTasks
echo Current directory: %CD%
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo CMD started with: !CMDCMDLINE!
endlocal
pause
endlocal

The execution of "Development + Test 99% (!)" or of "Development & Test 100% (!)" in C:\Temp results in %~f0 expanding to C:\Temp\Development + Test 99% (!) respectively C:\Temp\Development & Test 100% (!) without file extension .cmd. That is another quirks of cmd.
for %%I in ("%BatchName%") do set "BatchName=%%~sI" does not work in this case as CMD cannot find the file without file extension .cmd in the file system and the environment variable BatchName is not redefined with short 8.3 file name as generated by the file system for the batch file. The workaround is the call of GetBatchName resulting in getting really the fully qualified file name of the batch file assigned to the environment variable. Then the FOR command line results in assigning the short 8.3 file name of the batch file to the environment variable BatchName.
Does that always work? No, as it is possible to configure that the file system does not generate short 8.3 file names for all files and directories. It makes sense, especially for file servers, to disable the generation of short 8.3 file names as the file system becomes faster on doing that. That is the reason for the additional check if the fully qualified file name does not contain anymore an ampersand before running PowerShell. If that is not the case, the user is informed about this issue which cannot be worked around by command lines in the batch file, at least not with calling PowerShell with cmdlet Start-Process with -FilePath and -verb RunAs.
It is of course very often not possible to run a batch file from a network drive or a network resource using its UNC path which calls PowerShell or the Windows Script Host to start the Windows Command Processor again in the elevated execution environment of a local administrator if the user must switch to a different user account with such privileges. The batch file on the network drive/resource is most likely not read accessible in this case for the finally used account with local administrator privileges.
The string values under registry key HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console\%%Startup are read by conhost.exe and OpenConsole.exe (Windows Terminal app) and SystemSettings.exe (on viewing the Terminal setting).
cmd.exe runs conhost.exe. There is passed as argument usually the application/session identifier to which conhost should "connect" has hexadecimal number like 0x4. But when cmd.exe is executed as new process in an elevated execution environment, conhost.exe is started by cmd.exe with 0xffffffff as first argument (no existing session) and -ForceV1 as second argument.
The option -ForceV1 instructs conhost using the standard Windows console environment. The registry key HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console\%%Startup is completely ignored in this case.
It is intentionally designed by Microsoft that the execution of the Windows Command Processor in an elevated execution environment is done with using the standard console mode. A reason could be maximum downwards compatibility. Another reason could be maximum security. I don't know the reasons.
Is it possible that the batch file once processed by cmd.exe in elevated execution environment is running in a Terminal instead of standard Command Prompt (Windows Console Host) window?
Perhaps, if there are even more command lines added to start one more cmd.exe now in already elevated execution environment for execution in a Terminal window. But how this can be done is not the question. There must be really good reasons for doing that as a user of the batch file could be easily confused on double clicking on a batch file opening for a short time a Terminal or Windows Console window, then being asked by user account control for running Windows Command Processor as local administrator, then popping up for a short time once more a Windows Console window before a Terminal window is shown which perhaps is now longer visible for the user.
Other useful pages:

Understanding Windows Console Host Settings
Windows Terminal as your Default Command Line Experience
Windows Terminal command line arguments

